# How do include sub-folders in my file conversion script?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have modified a vbscript and batch file that allows me to convert HTML files to xlsx files in the current directory as follows

Script:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

xlsx_format = 51

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, xlsx_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Batch file:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.HTM* /b') DO to-xlsx.vbs "%%i" "%%~ni.xlsx"
del *.HTM /q
```

By including `/s` in the batch file I am able to convert files in the subfolders but they are still saved to the parent directory and I cant quite work out how to change that?

`src_file` is **C:\Converter\Subfolder\FileName** and `dest_file` is **C:\Converter\FileName** for a file in the subfolder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to change

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.HTM* /b') DO to-xlsx.vbs "%%i" "%%~ni.xlsx"
```

to

```
FOR /R %%i IN (*.HTM* ) DO to-xlsx.vbs "%%i" "%%~ni.xlsx"
```

`for /r` means *Recursive*, so you are asking CMD to loop every file and his subdirectories, but only that they contain an *`.htm*`* file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this works but still saves the converted file in the parent folder rather than in the sub-folder?

Comment: Try with `%%~dpi`, this means to get the directory of the selected file. It will be like `FOR /R %%i IN (*.HTM* ) DO to-xlsx.vbs "%%i" "%%~dpni.xlsx"`

Comment: I have additional query if you can help @Anic17? I am trying to run the batch file from vba using ```Call Shell(PathCrnt & "\Convert Files.bat", vbNormalFocus)``` which causes the batch file to use the default directory U:\ instead of the current directory, do you know why this might be?

Comment: Try adding `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the starting of the batch file, as it will CD to the directory where the batch file is located.

Comment: Amazing, cant thank you enough for your quick replies and correct solutions.